# React Native functional component navigationOptions headerRight not being set

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-functional-component

Previously I have set the headerRight option in the root component that renders child component with Screen options like this

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <RecipeProvider>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Recipes">
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Recipes"
            component={RecipeList}
            options={({ navigation }) => ({
              headerRight: () => (
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={styles.button}
                  onPress={() => navigation.navigate("New Recipe")}
                >
                  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus} size={20} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
              ),
            })}
          />
```

and now I would like to move the headerRight inside the component definition (so I don't end up with a huge App file with details that are only relevant to the screen component themselves)

I have read other solutions and tried the following

```
export default function RecipeList({ navigation }) {
  const { recipes } = useContext(RecipeContext);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        numColumns={2}
        data={recipes}
        keyExtractor={(recipe: Recipe) => recipe.id}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          return (
            <RecipeItem
              name={item.name}
              minutes={item.minutes}
              image={item.image}
              title="Go to Detail Screen"
              onPress={() => {
                navigation.navigate("Recipe Details", { item });
              }}
            />
          );
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

RecipeList.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
  headerRight: () => (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={styles.button}
      onPress={() => navigation.navigate("New Recipe")}
    >
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus} size={20} />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  ),
});
```

But the headerRight button doesn't show no more ... any ideas ?

Thank you all <3

Answer (score 0):

My headerRight is below and it works for me

```
EditScreen.navigationOptions = navData => {
 const submitFn = navData.navigation.getParam('submit');
  return {
    headerTitle: 'Edit Data'
    headerRight: (
     <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
       <Item
         title="Save"
          iconName={
            Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'md-checkmark' : 'ios-checkmark'
          }
        onPress={submitFn}
      />
     </HeaderButtons>
    )
   };
 };
```

Comment: later I found that `navigation.setOptions` works for setting the options within the component ... somehow the above doesn't work for me :( but thank you ! 